# How to validate the user in Active Directory in C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

How to validate the user in Active Directory in C#. The functionality is very strange, sometimes the user is authenticated even with the wrong password!

This is my first attempt

VERSION 1

```
var serverId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier( serverEdit.Text );

using( var connection = new LdapConnection( serverId ) ){
    TimeSpan mytimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
    var credential  = new NetworkCredential( userid, passwordEdit.Text );
    connection.AuthType =  AuthType.Negotiate;
    connection.Timeout = mytimeout;
    connection.Bind(credential);

   // VALID USER-PASSWORD
}
catch( Exception exception )
{
   // WRONG USER-PASSWORD
}
```

This is my second attempt

VERSION 2

```
try {
    using(var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,                         
           serverEdit.Text, "", ContextOptions.Negotiate,userId,  
           passwordEdit.Text))
    {
        if(!ctx.ValidateCredentials(userId,passwordEdit.Text, 
           ContextOptions.Negotiate)) {

            // WRONG USER/PASSWORD
        }
        else
        {
            var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx,userId);
            if( userPrincipal != null ) {
                DumpUserPrincipalData( userPrincipal );

                // VALID USER-PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
}
catch( Exception exception )
{
    // WRONG USER/PASSWORD
}
```

Comment: This has been discussed [many times before](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+validate+ad+credentials). If you are having trouble with one specific method, can you show the code you are using?

Comment: It 's true, I have tried almost all the proposed methods but nob I have found a definitive way.
I am frustrated by this uncertainty. It seems that once the user is validated, the second attempt also validates wrong passwords!

Comment: Can you show the code you are using that allows a wrong password?

Comment: Is the Guest account enabled on your domain? If so, any username/password will work. Although it was my understanding that if you provide a valid username with a wrong password, it would still fail.

Comment: you're absolutely right, I never thought of the guest user. Now I can never log in but it's another story, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Gabriel Luci, validation was always successful due to the presence of the Guest user.